# How to convert .shp or .kml file to Google Maps polygon coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, shapefile, google-polyline

I have a .shp file and tried to convert it with many tools (shp2kml, ESRI converter, qgis) into a kml file. When I take a closer look inside the kml file then the coordinates seems to differ from coordinates in the same area when I pin point a location in Google Maps. On the other hand, all shapes seem to be presented inside the kml file... however, I can't get them inside a Google Map (I want to use Google Maps not Google earth).

It's not my intention to let Google Maps read the .kml file because I would like to have the [polygons available for coding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple).

Now, I would like to convert the .kml (or the original .shp file) into Google Maps polygons (each shape a polygon). How can I achieve this?

Having the right coordinates for Google Maps polygons from the file will already be a big win for me. On Google, I could not find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at third party KML parsers ([geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) and [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/))?  They will take a KML file in the same domain and render it using native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects.

Comment: KML can be a pain at times with the Google Maps API.  I prefer to use [gdal's ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert a shapefile to GeoJSON.  GeoJSON is quite easy to convert to Google Maps types.  There is even a 3rd party JS library called [geojson-google-maps](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

if the feature object is an Poligon:

```
if (event.feature.getType()=='Polygon'){
    var gP = event.feature.getGeometry(); //return Polygon geometry object
    var gLG = gP.getArray()[0]; //return the LinearRing geometry object
    var arPnt = gLG.getArray(); //return the points of the LinearRing 
    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: arPnt });
}
```

In one line:

```
var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: event.feature.getGeometry().getArray()[0].getArray()});
```